# Leer un Archivo en red local con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, samba

Estaba desarrollando un simple scipt que lee un archivo que está en una red compartida. Lo que quiero hacer es leer un archivo que está en una carpeta compartida y ejecutar la lectura desde mi pc.

El código que tengo es este:

```
path = os.path.abspath('smb://192.168.1.1/prueba.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(path, header=0)
print(df)
```

Estoy utilizando linux lite 4 y para conectarme uso samba.

Comment: prueba con `smb://user@host/sharename`

Comment: ¿ Que problema tienes ? ¿ Funciona ? ¿ No funciona ? ¿ Errores ? ¿ El PC comienza a arder ?

Comment: Coloque de la forma que me indicaste: `path = os.path.abspath('smb://user@192.168.1.1/prueba.xlsx')` Pero sigue dando error: **IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

Comment: ¿Seguro que la IP `192.168.1.1` apunta a una computadora en particular?

Comment: Pudiste hacer algo?, estoy con el mismo problema. Puedo ingresar a todas las carpetas y manipular archivos mediante la navegación pero mis App hechas en python no se conectan con esas direcciones de red local.

Answer (score 0):

**OPCIÓN 1:**

Retira el `smb`, cambia las diagonales normales `/` por `\` diagonal invertida y usa una `r` antes de iniciar la cadena para que las diagonal inversa `\` no tenga ningún significado.

De esta manera:

```
path = os.path.abspath(r'\\192.168.1.1\prueba.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(path, header=0)
print(df)
```

**OPCIÓN 2:**

Por otra parte, también puedes hacer uso de la librería [jsmb](https://pypi.org/project/jsmb/)

Paquete de ayuda para usar SAMBA con Python con smb. Con el puedes listar, descargar, subir y remover archivos de directorios.

Lo primero es definir siempre la conexión y úsala como base para todos procesos.

**Conexion basica:**

```
con = jsmb.jsmb('ip','user','pass')
```

**Listar Archivos**

```
list = con.list('Nombre de Carpeta') for i in range(len(list)): print(list[i].filename)
```

**Subir archivos a servidor**

```
con.upload('Carpeta Compartida Inicial', 'archivo en tu maquina', 'Ubicacion del Archivo dentro de la carpeta')
```

**Descargar archivos del servidor**

```
con.download('Carpeta Compartida Inicial', 'Nombre del archivo en tu maquina', 'Ubicacion del Archivo en Carpeta Inicial')
```

**Eliminar archivos del servidor**

```
con.delete('Carpeta Compartida Inicial', 'Ubicacion del Archivo en Carpeta Inicial')
```

**Crear carpeta**

```
con.mkdir('Carpeta Compartida Inicial', 'carpeta/subcarpeta/subcarpeta')
```